# What do the phrases “connected therewith” and "direct contact" in Clausius's law mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, terminology, definition

I have questions about Clausius's law. The specific questions are:

> **【My Questions】**

- (1)What and what is connected in “connected therewith” in 【Quote 1】 below?
- (2) Give me some specific examples of "direct contact" and not "direct contact" in 【Quote 2】 below.

For question 1, Am I right if;
When "Heat transfer from the hot heat source to cold heat source" occurs, "some other change" always occurs at the same time?

For question 2, Am I right if; 
Positive heat may flow from "cold heat source A" to the "high-temperature heat source B" only when there is a "region where the temperature cannot be determined" between the low-temperature heat source A and the high-temperature heat source B?

The original text of Clausius's principle is extracted below:

> **【Quote 1】** (ref.1)
>   ”Heat can never pass from a colder to a warmer body without some other change, connected therewith, occurring at the same time.   ”

A book has the following statement as a supplementary explanation of Clausius's principle.

> **【Quote 2】** (ref. 1)
>   " But with direct contact, even with  man's intervention, heat can never pass from cold to warm."

【Reference】:
(Ref.1) 
[Block by Block: the Historical and Theoretical Foundations of Thermodynamics](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=lLXRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA447&lpg=PA447&dq=Heat+can+never+pass+from+a+colder+to+a+warmer+body+without+some+other+change,+connected+therewith,+occurring+at+the+same+time.&source=bl&ots=VsctGv0odL&sig=ACfU3U0T5wccwKZtGBSHyqutuSM2dlRECA&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQkbzdnYLoAhXBBKYKHW1IAscQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Heat%20can%%2020never%20pass%20from%20a%20colder%20t%20o%20a%20warmer%20body%20without%20some%20other%20change%2C%20connected%20therewith%2C%20occurring%20at%20the%20same%20time.&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the quotes in context, in the first quote I believe “connected therewith” means a device located between the bodies (i.e heat pump/refrigerator).

In the second quote “direct contact” means without a such a device, such as heat transferring spontaneously by conduction from a cold cold to a hot body  touching each other in violation of the second law.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful.